# is there any connection between the consistent histories interpretation of quantum mechanics and kripke semantics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lo.logic

Kripke semantics interpret intuitionistic logic by a partially ordered set of worlds/situations. Consistent histories interpretation of QM elaborates the copenhagen interpretation where a consistent set of histories can be assigned probabilities.

I don't really understand either of these formalisms, but it does appear on the face of it that the formalisms should have something in common, do they?

Comment: Check out the topos approaches to quantum mechanics, as initiated by Isham/Butterfield and Döring/Isham (the contravariant approach, see review by Flori: http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5660). There's also a covariant approach, developed by Heunen, Landsman and Spitters (see Wolters' comparison of the approaches: http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.2031). That should get you started.

Comment: Isham addresses the topic specifically in 'Topos Theory and Consistent Histories' http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9607069.

Comment: great, thanks for both these references.